# Why is my CSS differently displayed on a webserver than a localhost?

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio-code, hosting

I have uploaded my site on a host server Combell. But when I go on my website with my domain name, my CSS is completely messed up. Especially the width. When I'm running my website locally with the extension Live Server, my website looks perfecty how I wanted to be. What's the problem?
Here are some screens from the host server from combell.
[image: Here are some screens on the from the host server from combell.]

[image: Here are some screens on the from the host server from combell.]

And Here are the screens of my localhost on my computer using the extention live server.
[image: Here are the screens of my localhost on my computer using the extention live server.]

[image: Here are the screens of my localhost on my computer using the extention live server.]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/CSS/index.css" />
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/670c71c898.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
   
    <title>Home</title>
  </head>
```

http://fayssal-ghojdam.be/

Comment: Please show us your codes (e.g. if you use  <link rel="stylesheet" href="c:\test\styles.css"> in your localhost, then in a linux server it will fail)

Comment: @KenLee Yes, that's what I did. What should I do ?

Comment: Thanks . Can you post your actual URL too ?

Comment: @KenLee It's done.

Comment: Hi, I just checked your site, it should be fine if the browser setting is set to say zoom to "50%" (viewed at  http://fayssal-ghojdam.be/) . Hence please check whether your zoom settings are different when you view the site in localhost and in server. If this is the case, you need to further change your CSS so that the text will not get overlapped

Comment: @KenLee  Thank you very much. But can you please tell me how can I avoid this. Because not everyone will have the reflex of zooming out 50%. x)

Comment: The 1st step is to adjust the set the max-width of the elements in your CSS , (e.g. img_container, now the width is width: 1400px;), you should add max-width say 70% / 100% so that even if the user zoom in / zoom out, the contents / images inside will not get too large to have overlapping. Hope that this can help. You may also wish to set all image to have max-width to be 100%  by `img {max-width:100%;}`

Answer (score 0):

Please check your browser zoom settings. (it appears to be ok if you say zoom to 50%)

To avoid future problem, please see my comments in your post. Thanks

Comment: Done, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Thanks . Can you post your actual URL? (you may edit your post)

Comment: Thank you very much. But can you please tell me how can I avoid this. Because not everyone will have the reflex of zooming out 50%. x)